# VS2005 - Unable to add reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word (Office 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2005, ms-office, office-interop

Running WinXP SP3, Visual Studios 2005, .NET 2.0. Recently upgraded machine from Office 2007 to Office 2010 sp1.

I had a project that referenced Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word and when I reopened it the reference was not found. I've checked the Office install CD and ".NET Programmability Support" is selected as installed. If I go to C:\Windows\assembly I see Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word Version 14.0.0.0 installed on the list.

When I go to Add Reference .NET tab, the only Office references I see are Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.

I can go to the COM tab and add Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library to get the reference to Microsoft.Office.Core. However I have been unable to find a way to reference the Interop assembly.

Doing a file search on my machine for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll also finds no matches.

I've repaired the Office install and still no luck. I also tried to install the PIAs directly, same behavior.

Could this be an issue with trying to use Office 2010's interop assembly with VS2005? I saw online that the directory the dll is found in is usually under Program Files\Visual Studios 10.

Any thoughts on what step I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can install Office 2010 PIA separately. Installer can be downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3508

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried. I ran the o2010pia.msi file and it seems like it installs correctly. I can see it on Add/Remove programs. However the dll is still not found and the .NET Reference is still not there for Interop.Word.

Comment: I would try to search for them. E.g. using a locate32 program (very handy for searching files on disks)

Comment: I tried a Windows Search for "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll". No results.

Comment: I followed the link, In my .NET 2.0 Configuration I see Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word version 14.0.0.0. I then tried to CD to the directory to run the regasm command and the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word directory doesn't exist under %windir%\assembly\GAC. The only office folder is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Owc11